# Why did Tonks want to visit Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Harry is snooping around, trying to catch Malfoy. Once, he runs into Tonks on the seventh floor corridor, who says that she wants to visit Dumbledore.

Later at the end of the book, in the hospital wing:

> And the meaning of Tonks’s Patronus and her mouse-colored hair, and the reason she had come running to find Dumbledore when she had heard a rumor someone had been attacked by Greyback, all suddenly became clear to Harry; it had not been Sirius that Tonks had fallen in love with after all.

Apparently Harry understands that Tonks had fallen in love with Lupin & why Tonks came to visit Dumbledore.

But I don't. What has Dumbledore got to do with Tonks & Lupin's relationship?

Why did Tonks visit Dumbledore?

Answer (score 3):

Lupin has a special relationship with Greyback as you can read in chapter sixteen of HBP:

> “You haven’t heard of him?” Lupin’s hands closed convulsively in his lap. “Fenrir Greyback is, perhaps, the most savage werewolf alive today. He regards it as his mission in life to bite and to contaminate as many people as possible; **he wants to create enough werewolves to overcome the wizards**. Voldemort has promised him prey in return for his services. Greyback specializes in children…Bite them young, he says, and raise them away from their parents, raise them to hate normal wizards. Voldemort has threatened to unleash him upon people’s sons and daughters; it is a threat that usually produces good results.”
> Lupin paused and then said, **“It was Greyback who bit me.”**

So he bit Lupin as a child to change him and recruit him for his army of werewolves. But it failed: Lupin now is a werewolf, but he did not join him.
For Greyback he is a traitor. That's why it is likely for him to attack Lupin whenever they meet. Not to bite him again but to kill.

So when Tonks heard of somebody being attacked by Greyback she was immediately frightened it might have been Lupin. And therefore she needed information and advice from Dumbledore. Not because he could be "turned to werewolf" more, but because he could be fatally injured.

Comment: When Lupin said - "*It was Greyback who bit me*", he meant it when he was a child, he wasn't referring to the incident in HBP.

Comment: Yeah and why would he want to bight the poor fellow again  ?

Comment: ok, made clear that the biting incidenct was, when Lupin was a child... just wanted to show the (long) connection between Greyback and Lupin... and added an explanation, why Lupin is likely to be attacked by Greyback

Comment: There's more information in Chapter Sixteen, just before the quote you already have. Lupin had been among werewolves spying for Dumbledore (it's unclear if he was going to return to live among them *after* visiting The Burrow for Christmas), which would be more motivation for Greyback to attack him.

Comment: So: that's the REAL reason for her to be concerned... thanx for the information

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: You should add that as another answer. Otherwise I will look for that quote and edit it in my own answer...